# SQL: How to get max over column but exclude certain values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a numeric column and all I want is the maximum value in that column that does NOT exceed a certain number. I am doing this along with a group by statement, using the `MAX` function.

So basically if for each group, the column is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, and I want the maximum that does not exceed `4`, then in this case, the maximum for this group would be 4.

However, if the column equals `5, 6, 7, 8`, then since all values exceed 4, I … actually don't care, this won't end up being displayed, so just return anything.

How do I do this? Using SQL/Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
Select case when count(case when col > 4 then 1 end) = count(*)
           then max(col) 
           else max(case when col <= 4 then col end) 
       end as res_
  From your_table t
```

Comment: I don't understand. What's the point of the first branch of the `case` expression? The OP said he doesn't care what is shown if all values are > 4. So, why not just return `null` in that case?

Comment: @mathguy you are right. OP can use whatever he wants to instead of `max(col)`

Comment: I like this answer even if it did more than necessary, since the extra code shows me more clearly what the logic is, and allows me to expand on it.

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(case when col>4 then 0 else col end) from table1
```

Comment: This assumes that negative values are not possible in the column. We don't know if that is true or not - the OP didn't tell us. Best to return `null` when `col > 4`.

Comment: @mathguy really? please read the description where he listed the possible range of values. btw, returning null can have unintended consequences.

Comment: I don't see a "possible range of values", where is that? All I see are a couple of *examples*, but the OP didn't say anywhere that "those are the only possible values". As to `null` having unintended consequences - the OP already said he is not going to display anything for those groups anyway, so even if I were to agree with what you said, how does that matter?

Comment: @mathguy I don't think any of this matter either.

Answer (score 1):

If that is all that the query needs to do, it is best to filter the rows with `col > 4` **before** aggregation, in a `where` clause. This will reduce the amount of work done by the aggregation itself, which is the most expensive operation in the whole query.

As a side effect, "groups" where all values in the column are > 4 will not be included at all in the output. For some reporting tasks this would be a problem, but you said in your case you wouldn't show anything in the output for those groups anyway.

So, you could do something like this:

```
select agg_col1, agg_col2, ..., max(col) as max_col_up_to_4
from   your_table
WHERE  col <= 4                  --  DO THE FILTERING HERE!
group  by agg_col1, agg_col2, ...
;
```

(Here `agg_col1, agg_col2, ...` are, obviously, the columns by which you group for your aggregation.)